# Why did Dignam wear gloves and hospital moccasins in 'The Departed' while killing Sullivan?

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, the-departed

In the final scene of The Departed when Sullivan (played by Matt Damon)returns to his apartment he finds Dignam (Mark Wahlberg) waiting wearing gloves and hospital moccasins and pointing a gun at him. Dignam just walks off after shooting Sullivan. What was the significance of the gloves and moccasins? If Dignam was taking precautions for not leaving any evidence or sign on the murder site, then how did they help? Or is there some other reason?

[image]

Comment: You never watched *CSI*, did you? ;)

Comment: Not much, but now I see what you mean !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You’re right.  He wore the shoe covers, gloves, and a hair net to not leave traces behind, what is called “cross-contamination”.  This just improves his chances of not getting caught.

More info and pictures via [here](http://www.nfstc.org/pdi/Subject01/pdi_s01_m01_03.htm)

> "Biological evidence requires care to guard against the possibility of cross contamination either by the investigator or by other biological specimens at the scene. Equipment is available to crime scene investigators which aide in the prevention of cross contamination.  Types of equipment include:
>
> Tyvek white paper body suit
>
> Paper mask that covers nose and mouth
>
> Eye protection
>
> Latex or Nitrile gloves
>
> Sleeve protectors
>
> **Shoe covers**
>
> Hair net"